# c++ class function does not work as intended inside another function

Tags: c++, function, class

To demonstrate my problem let's look at the following sample:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
public:
    long double x, y;
    MyClass(const long double &xx = 0, const long double &yy = 0);
    long double distance(const MyClass &b) {
        return sqrt((x - b.x)*(x - b.x) + (y - b.y)*(y - b.y));
    }
};

MyClass::MyClass(const long double &xx, const long double &yy) {
    x = xx; y = yy;
}

void WriteDistance(const MyClass &a, const MyClass &b) {
    cout << a.distance(b) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass a = MyClass(2., 3.);
    MyClass b = MyClass(3., 4.);
    cout << a.distance(b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There is a class `MyClass` and there is a class function distance which takes one `MyClass` variable and returns the distance between an existing point and the argument point.

The problem is: in the main(), the function works (gives no error). However there are errors in the WriteDistance() function, that reads: `the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "MyClass::distance"` and `'long double MyClass::distance(const MyClass &)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const MyClass' to 'MyClass &'`.

If I overload the distance function (to take not only one MyClass object, but perhaps also two long doubles, just for the comfort of availability), the error reads: `no instance of overloaded function "MyClass::distance" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match)` and `'MyClass::distance': 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer`.

The question is: why this error occurs and how to prevent it? I found out that not making the `MyClass &a` `const` (so deleting "`const`") gets rid of the error. But why? Members of this site told me countless times to always pass by `const` reference to prevent copying of objects. If I cannot pass by `const` reference, does that mean that my function `WriteDistance` changes the a object in some way in the process? Is there some workaround to being able to having it really `const`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `distance` function claims to modify the object it is called on, which is why you can't use it on values of type `const MyClass`.

You should declare it as

```
long double distance(const MyClass &b) const {
//                                     ^^^^^
```

This second `const` means it won't modify class members (i.e. `*this` is `const` within the function).

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I realized what the probilem is with what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Declare the member function with the qualifier const

```
long double distance(const MyClass &b) const {
//...
```

If you want to declare the function with two parameters then make it static. For example

```
static long double distance(const MyClass &a, const MyClass &b) {
//...
```

Comment: This is interesting: "If you want to declare the function with two parameters then make it static." could you explain why?

Answer (score -1):

You need add a **const** qualification version function for the **const** object' usage. We usually provide two version function declaration, const and non-const.
 The const version is used for const Class object, like your **const MyClass &b**

```
void WriteDistance(const MyClass &a, const MyClass &b) const {
    cout << a.distance(b) << endl;
}
```

Comment: not my downvote, but providing a const and a non-const version of a method that actually is const is rather pointless, because you can call a const method on a non-const object (just not the other way around). Moreover passing two parameters instead of making it a member function is an option, but for free functions the `) const {` is wrong